# Local server on iPad

Tags: iphone, http, ipad, streaming

We have an application which would involve HTTP live streaming. As per the documentation, I can encode my streams and provide the encryption key url (if the key is stored on remote server) in the index file (m3u8).
I want to know if it is possible to store the key locally on the ipad and refer to it locally somehow in the index file. Is it possible to have a local server running on the ipad and provide a localhost url in index files? If so, would the server be bundled with the app build?

Thanks,
Hetal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cocoahttpserver](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/) is a HTTP Server on top of [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

I haven't done streaming with it, but the homepage says

> Asynchronous networking using standard Cocoa sockets/streams

Comment: I just want to save my key.txt file on it so that the player can fetch it if I provide a url something like http://localhost/key.txt