# How do I upload files using http/ftp to iphone/ipad? (Eg. ifile, goodreader)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, file-upload

Is there any good advice on uploading files to the device? I've seen many apps create a http server on 80 or 8080 to upload files. Does that mean I have to implement a server too?

Are there any 3rd-party libraries? (Preferably open-source and non-GPL)

EDIT: I am going to upgrade files in the app for specific devices in a corporate environment, so the ipad pulling files from a central server is also an alternative. But I would have to send messages to these ipads to tell them to fetch those files.

Comment: So you want the file transfer via HTTP instead of using iTunes sync or dropbox?

Comment: I would like to mass push file updates to specific devices in a corporate environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume what you want is a kind of *automatic update*. An app do something by order from server without user's manual operation.

I don't know enterprise-license specific feature of iOS. But I believe there's no such enterprise-specific APIs. And as I know, *automatic update* is almost impossible. Because,

1. There is no system-level support for automatic update. (yet?)
2. So messaging and fetching feature should be implemented in app.
3. But no app is guaranteed to run in background for long time.
4. And also user can turn off any app at any time.
5. There is no way to send message to an app which is not running.
6. Even you can send, there is no way to address each client form the server.

If your app is running, sending message or commanding them to fetch or do anything is just a simple work. The problem is **there is no regular way to force them always keep alive.** Even under situations like OS reboot or abnormal termination.

However there is an alternative. Just registering app as VOIP app like Skype. OS does not keep the app running too, but will monitor specific socket port, and will wake your app when the socket receives some message. For more details, see here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW15

In AppStore, an app using VOIP for other purpose like automatic update will not be passed, but you have no need to concern about it.

And other way to send message to device without running app is *push notification*. This is a feature supported in system-level. But this is not designed to commanding app. This is designed to send textual message. So If your app is not running, the message will be displayed to user. However, you can guide the user to start the app by sending push notification.

As a final option, you can request some feature to Apple for enterprise environment. If your company is big enough to get an enterprise license, Apple will consider your feature request seriously.

---

If you decided to use VOIP method, I'm sorry I can't help you any more. I have no experience of implementing this kind of app. But it should not so hard.

However hard part is server. It definitely require custom server program which keeps TCP/IP connection. Regular HTTP server cannot be used. Because HTTP itself is designed as not to keep TCP/IP connection. You have to build this kind of server yourself from scratch. You'll have to handle lower level TCP/IP transmissions.

There are a few solutions(both of free/commercial) for this kind of server, but none of are popular because this kind of server regularly needs full customization. So there's nothing to re-use or share.

However I believe this is most suitable implementation for your app.

---

If you can satisfy automatic update only when the app is running, you can archive it by polling server status from the client periodically.

This is easy to implement because you can use regular HTTP servers for this. Client connect and download recent updates from central server periodically. If there is a new update, just fetch and do what you want. And the app is launched, just check the update at first. Prevent all operation until update applied.

This is regular way. Most of applications are built with this method. In this case, you have no need to implement server or hard thing.

However applying speed of update is depend on polling period.

---

(Edit)

I couldn't care about private APIs. Because your app is not for AppStore, so you can use private API's freely. (This is different thing with jail-breaking. There are so many *hidden* features by excluded from documentation) I don't know about private APIs, but it's possible there is some API which enable the support for keep-alive of the app.
However, this *reverse engineering* work is so painful unless you're born to hack.

Comment: Does anyone know if node.js suits the server Eonil mentions?

Comment: @Tians It looks `node.js` has ability to send binary data via TCP/IP socket. However, as I know, the server program should run long time  keeping all connections. But I don't believe `node.js` is stable as the required level. And also, it is designed as HTTP server primariliy. I recommend online game server implementation for this purpose.

Comment: **The VOIP hack is completely unnecessary.**

In [Completing a Finite Length Task in the Background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW12)
Apple says _"You can use task completion to ensure that important but potentially long-running operations do not end abruptly when the user leaves the application. For example, you might use this technique to save user data to disk or finish downloading an important file from a network server."_

Comment: @skue Keep-alive support for the feature is not enough for this purpose. Imagine situations like OS reboot and abnormal termination. OS will automatically re-launches the VOIP apps in the situation.

Comment: @Eonil So your recommendation is to run the user's battery down pretending to be a VOIP app just to cover the corner case where the OS spontaneously reboots while your app is downloading new content? (Instead of just resuming when the app is restarted?) I don't understand why anyone would work so hard against the API when it already gives you what you need.

Comment: @skue Me too. Your suggestion is generally better behavior and strongly recommended design by Apple. So I don't try to make what I said :) It is just description about a possibility. Maybe he/she's in unescapable situation which requires any kind of help... However you're right about not implementing VOIP hack is better behavior design for better life.

Answer (score 3):

> But I would have to send messages to
>   these ipads to tell them to fetch
>   those files.

[Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Or mail with custom URL scheme for launching your application.

[iOS Application Programming Guide - Implementing Custom URL Schemes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW7)

Comment: could you give an example how mail with custom URL scheme works? Does that mean I will have to manually receive mail and click the url? Is automated pushing available?

Comment: "Does that mean I will have to manually receive mail and click the url?" Yes. "Is automated pushing available?" I think, No. Even "[Over-the-Air Profile Delivery Concepts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/OTASecurity/OTASecurity.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009505-CH3-SW1)" needs the user operations as far as my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use the following open-source in your project:

http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/

https://github.com/robin/cocoa-web-resource/wiki

Answer (score 1):

Apple has some sample code on their website that details exactly what you're looking for:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CocoaHTTPServer/CocoaHTTPServer.zip

Answer (score 1):

So you have a couple options:

1. You could distribute your app wirelessly within your organization and push new content out as app updates. Apple provides this option to their [Enterprise Developers](http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/integration/).

   > **Wireless App Distribution**
   >
   > iPhone enables enterprises to securely host and wirelessly distribute in-house apps to employees over Wi-Fi and 3G. Apps can be updated without requiring users to connect to their computers. In-house apps can be hosted on any web server accessible to users. Users simply tap on a URL to install apps wirelessly without needing to connect to their computers.
2. The alternative is you configure the app to fetch the updated data. You describe adding an HTTP server to the iOS device, but there's no way the server can receive data when the app isn't running. Given your needs, it would probably work better to embed a web client in your app instead.

   If I was in your shoes (and option #1 didn't work), I'd use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to check with a server at launch/daily. If there are new updates, the app could then either prompt the user that there are new data files to download, or it could just silently download them in a background thread.

   UPDATED: Perhaps I should have been more explicit about how to do #2. You can configure the download so it isn't interrupted when the user quits the app (you don't need to do a Voip hack). Check out the [Completing a Finite Length Task in the Background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW12) section in the iOS Programming Guide.

Comment: The problem is I am distributing my application in another organization, which shouldn't count as in-house, or is it?

Comment: Why not? It's certainly in-house within that organization. The organization simply needs an enterprise account with Apple, and there's no reason you (as their consultant) can't help them set this up.

Answer (score 1):

There are http server [sample codes](http://situee.blogspot.com/2011/03/http-web-server-file-upload-on-iphone.html) from Apple and open source community such as cocoahttpserver TouchHTTPD.
You can upload file to the http server on iphone.

Here's a blog and screen-shots about [running cocoahttpserver and upload file to iphone](http://situee.blogspot.com/2011/03/cocoahttpserver-http-server-file-upload.html).

Answer (score -2):

The Python CGIHTTPServer allows you to create a server in 0 lines of code:

```
jcomeau@intrepid:~/rentacoder/bin2txt$ python -m CGIHTTPServer
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

Actually implementing a script to parse the input and save the file would take a little more effort.

[later]
OK, so forget about that, Apple doesn't allow it. See [Local server on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569770/local-server-on-ipad) for the iPad at least.

Comment: I do not know if Python is available for non-jailbroken iGadgets.

Comment: Notice that I am implementing a server on the device, where python is not applicable.

Comment: OK, wasn't sure. I figured iPad had it, and I have Python on my jailbroken iPod Touch.

Comment: why are you guys downvoting me? I put that cocoahttpserver link in back on Feb 25.